# Can a mostly static PHP class be instantiated within itself as an 'okay' practice?

Tags: php, class, static, instantiation

I am reviewing some code a colleague of mine has written and I am trying to wrap my head around his design. It appears they have a class that is mostly static, but has a private constructor method. Within the class, there are methods that then construct new objects from that same class. Is this considered an 'okay' practice? Or is this kind of a [wonky](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wonky) way of doing a class?

Here's the abstract code:

```
class ABC
{
    static public $PROP1 = 'car';
    static public $PROP2 = 'blue';
    static public $PROP3 = 'apple';

    static public function method1($arg)
    {
        return new ABC($arg, true);
    }

    private function __construct($arg, $isFlag = false)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First thing that came to mind was a factory pattern. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: +1 to @SchautDollar, also I believe `new DB(` should be `new ABC(`.

Comment: the good thing about doing like that is that you can pass this static function reference as an argument of other functions

Comment: Thanks @RichardMarskell-Drackir, that was correct. Forgot to change that when abstracting =]

Comment: @Oddant you can do that with instance methods as well.

Comment: if his static class keeps track of named instances of itself that it creates then its using a pattern called a [multiton](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether it's OK or not depends on what the class is used for.

Anyway, the kind of architecture you're describing is sometimes used for different purposes. The [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern is a good application of such pratice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This answer was chosen over @Oddant's because it touches on my question, and takes it a step further with providing a resource. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

This singleton pattern makes you having more control on the way your class needs to be expressed throughout your program.

let say you want to instanciate only 5 Objects of the same class, you can easily implements that with a counter in the static method.

That is sometimes called 'Factory pattern' as you will notice the way you manage the creation of instances (products).

Answer (score 0):

If you had a family of objects that shared most of their state this **may** be a sane approach. I can't imagine a situation though that wouldn't be better just to abstract the shared state into it's own object and inject it into each of the new instances. IMHO public statics are almost as evil as globals.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be the so called factory pattern.

if you declare the constructor private you can not instanciate the class directly.
You have to use the public static methods to use such a class.

Patterns are really great! you should read something about them.